# How to delete files attached to entities

Tags: 2sxc

Right now im using App.Data.Delete(entityId, userName) to delete entities in some cases, but files attached to that entities are not being deleted.

How I can delete files too.

Comment: At the moment there is no built in API to do this. The challenge is that the files should be removed both on the file system and also in the platform (DNN/Oqtane) list of files from the DB. For now, you would need to write the code yourself, or contribute to 2sxc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, maybe you have some way to obtain file id from current 2sxc record, to try to delete manually that file from DNN ?

Comment: if you use AsAdam (before deleting) you will get objects that have everything, incl. the FileIDs

Comment: Thanks I already tried with AsAdam method and was able to delete files